# Does sbt !: output to file

Tags: scala, sbt

I am playing with sbt, and I would like to export the last few commands into a file.

I can get history of commands with `!:`, so is it possible to have something like

```
!: >> output.txt
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it already stored in a file.
For more details you can check: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Howto/interactive.html

By default, interactive history is stored in the target/ directory for the current project (but is not removed by a clean). History is thus separate for each sub-project. The location can be changed with the historyPath setting, which has type Option[File]. For example, history can be stored in the root directory for the project instead of the output directory:

```
historyPath <<= baseDirectory(t => Some(t / ".history"))
```

The history path needs to be set for each project, since sbt will use the value of historyPath for the current project (as selected by the project command).

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy your history file, from which these last lines are taken upon `!` call or take a look at https://github.com/steppenwells/sbt-sh, which allows you to interact with shell intuitively.